# rails delegates vs wrapper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

What's the benefit of delegating? Are there additional reasons other than as a convenience method? How does it compare to a simple wrapper method in the model?

Without delegates I'd have:

```
Class Goal
  belongs_to :user
end

 Time.now.in_time_zone(goal.user.timezone)
```

Now with delegates, are there advantages to:

```
Class Goal
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :timezone, :to => :user

  ...
end

Time.now.in_time_zone(goal.timezone)
```

versus a wrapper method:

```
Class Goal
  belongs_to :user
  def tz
    self.user.timezone
  end

  ...
end

Time.now.in_time_zone(goal.tz)
```

I think I prefer the wrapper method because I can give it an arbitrary alias, (though perhaps if I were to rtfm it may be possible with delegate as well). Is there other stuff going on here? (it doesn't seem I can query based on delegated keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are more or less equivalent, the only difference is a little bit of exception handling code to let you know if you're delegating to a `nil` object.  To use your example, `delegate :timezone, :to => :user` would generate this timezone method:

```
def timezone(*args, &block)
  user.__send__(:timezone, *args, &block)
rescue NoMethodError
  if user.nil?
    raise "Goal#timezone delegated to user.timezone, but user is nil: #{self.inspect}"
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

You can't use an arbitrary alias, but you can provide a `prefix`.  You can also use the `allow_nil` option to generate a slightly different version of the method that won't raise when the delegate object is `nil`.

For more information see the [`delegate` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) or the [`delegate` source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8ba491acc31bf08cf63a83ea0a3c314c52cd020f/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L104).